# Laravel Passport token length

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Using passport for api authentication for a mobile app. The app devs were quick to complain about the size of the access_token provided (1071 characters) and having to pass it in each request.

On investigation the bulk of the token is the signature portion. By default passport is generating a 4096bit rsa key. I found i can reduce the token size to 559 characters by generating a 1024bit key instead. Better, but still much larger than keys generated by other services like Facebook.

I can not find much info on the subject, Is it a moot point? Is 1KB token nothing to complain about? Is reducing the key size a bad idea? Anything else that can be done to reduce the size?

**Update:**
We have decided to continue without any changes to the key size.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? I too can lower the token size by reducing the key to 1024 bit but it still feels far too big. Surely not all Laravel Passport servers are generating keys this big?

Comment: Sorry no, we didn’t have time to investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

try this for shorter access token:

```
php artisan  passport:keys  --length=512 --force
```

Comment: it's still too long for a small app, can be shorter?  i tried `--length=256` but doesn't work

Comment: it gives error "The "--length" option does not exist." when i run the command